# Classes declared dynamically with GuidAttribute

Tags: c#, com

I have a t4 template that creates many classes based on a database table. These classes need to be exposed to COM, so they are declared with the `GuidAttribute` attribute.

Whenever I compile the project, say to test something and register it in the test environment, new GUIDs are created for each class definition, and I'm starting to worry that I may be doing bad things to the Windows Registry...

If I compile the project and I have the definition of `Class1` like

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[GuidAttribute("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA")]
public class Class1
{
    ...
}
```

And tomorrow I want to test something else and `Class1` now looks like

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[GuidAttribute("BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB")]
public class Class1
{
    ...
}
```

Will the previous GUID remain in the registry, or is the registration process smart enough to remove everything from the previous registration?

This whole question may come from my ignorance of what are these GUIDs used for and how they relate to CLSIDs, but the fact that they are meant to be declared *statically* with the class definition, and I'm doing it dynamically makes me somewhat uneasy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will the previous GUID remain in the registry

If you don't explicitly unregister the component, yes.  Easy to forget of course.  You have to run Regasm.exe /uninstall from an elevated command prompt.

> is the registration process smart enough to remove everything

Depends how you register.  If you let MSBuild do it (Project + Properties, Build tab, Register for COM interop option) then it will automatically unregister the server before rebuilding the DLL.  But since you use [Guid], it immediately writes it back of course :)  Net effect is zero.  If you do it by hand by running Regasm.exe then no unregistration takes place.

Do keep in mind that [Guid] is sacred in COM.  Explicitly specifying like you do is quite risky, there is a rock-hard rule in COM that you *must* change the guid when you change the declaration.  Not doing so causes very nasty DLL Hell problems.  Using the [Guid] attribute is only reasonable when you have to write a replacement for an existing COM server.  Or to avoid registry pollution when you don't let MSBuild clean up or want to avoid a client programming tool hassling you with constantly having to re-select the type library.  But then it is very important that you remove the attribute again when you are done testing.  Easy to forget of course :)

Comment: So would you say declaring the GUID explicitly is a bad practice in my case? I only do it like that because I read in another question that it was necessary so the client *sees* the definition of the class; for example, before I added those attributes to the classes, in a VB6 project, Intellisense wouldn't display member information...

Comment: That has nothing to do with the [Guid] attribute.  ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual is the one that's required to power IntelliSense.  In itself not such a great way to do it since it exposes too much info.  Declaring the interface explicitly and using ClassInterfaceType.None on the class that implements it is the better way.

Comment: I see... yeah I just removed it from the template and the members are visible :). Regarding your suggestion of not using AutoDual... what do you mean with "too much info"? Are you referring to the .NET methods like `Equals`, `GetType` and such? Or is there something darker/dangerous going on with the AutoDual attribute?

Comment: Yes, those.  As well as any other implementation method that you didn't actually mean to be visible, if any.